# Should I use "get"-prefix in my method name?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter

I have this abstract class that is used as data repository.

```
public abstract class AbstractDataSource {
    public abstract DataRow getDataRow(Key key); //or just dataRow(Key key)???
}

public class CSVDataSource extends AbstractDataSource {
    @Override
    public DataRow getDataRow(Key key) { //or just dataRow(Key key)??
        //fetch row from file and return dataRow
        //....
        return dataRow;
    }
}
```

More specific classes (i.e. subclasses of this class) implement methods for different data source, e.g. CSV, ARFF and other formats.

I was wondering if the "get"-Keyword is appropriate here, as the data retrieval is not just returning a variable, but could also require filesystem access or whatsoever.

So should I use the "get"-prefix or not?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend using `retrieve` as this indicates that something more complex is happening than just getting a value

Comment: I like retrieve for this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that using the `get` keyword can sometimes seem non-intuitive when there's real logic behind. In your case `lookup` or `find` prefixes could be good substitues. There's also `retrieve` as suggested by @Thomas.

This question might seem off topic at first. But naming is, at least to me, an integral part of good application  design.

Comment: +1. Not just real logic, but also real chance of raising an exception.

Comment: What about boolean getters? What to use instead of is- prefix?

Comment: What about calculated properties like the size in the `List`? It doesnt have a `get` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to this method to be a [bean getter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean), so you can use it with things like [BeanUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)?  Given that it is doing heavy I/O and some logic, probably not, so I would name it differently.